# Facebook sharing with sharekit does not link to my app

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I'm using ShareKit to share with Facebook and twitter, I just noticed it doesn't link to my app anymore, I don't know if this is due to a sharekit or iOS update, but now it just says via iOS, and links to iOs' page (apple.com/ios):

[image: Sample]

So before it used to say via "AppName" now it doesn't. I've overridden the following methods (with correct values):

```
-(NSString*)appName {
    return @"appName";
}
-(NSString*)appURL {
    return @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/....";
}
```

Still the post says via iOS. The only difference I've noticed is that before, a "web" dialog appeared, and now it's the iOS dialog:

[image: iOS]

How can I make it say my app's name and link?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ShareKit, but it's using the native iOS6 share sheet which does not give app attribution. I assume ShareKit has some precedence order, where it will try to share using the iOS6 share sheet first (if available), and then use web dialog as a backup. If you want attribution, you should see if you can disable the iOS6 share sheet in ShareKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up removing ShareKit (fattens the binary) and using the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios)